# How to implement NTLM authentication in Spring-Security with csrf enabled .

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, csrf, ntlm

I want to implement NTLM authentication in Spring-boot using Spring-security with CSRF enabled. is there a way to implement it without ignoreAntMatch the URL or .jsp page in which NTLM authentication code is written or can we write NTLM authentication code in a class.
my application uses two authentication, LDAP and NTML.
For login, I ask user id and password for LDAP authentication. But for NTLM I need userid, but due to CSRF, the NTLM page redirects to login.